# Error al validar formulario con compound

Tags: validación, symfony2

Buenas, tengo dos formularios, uno de ellos se basa en una colección de elementos del otro. El formulario funciona bien con los eventos pero falla cuando lo envío siempre me devuelve un error que es el siguiente:

> Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[registrosusuario] =
>   Object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)
>
> Caused by:
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
>   Compound forms expect an array or NULL on submission.

He estado mirando y creo que el fallo está en el evento `PRE_SET_DATA`. El problema es que si lo elimino no me enseña los valores al imprimir los valores en twig. Siempre me salen en blanco.

El código de mis formularios:

AsistenciaType:

```
class AsistenciaType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fecha', DateTimeType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'html5' => false,
                'label' => "Fecha",
                'compound'=>false
            ))

            ->add('comentario', TextareaType::class, array(
                'attr'=>array(
                    'rows'=>5
                )
            ))
            ->add('enviar', SubmitType::class,
                array(
                    'label'=>'Enviar',
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn-info btn-block btn-lg'
                    ))
            );

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();

                $fecha = $data->getFecha();
                if(is_null($fecha)){
                    $registros =  array();
                } else {
                    $datos = $this->em->getRepository('ControlAsistenciaBundle:RegistroTiempo')
                        ->ObtenerRegistrosFechaUsuario($data->getUsuario(), $fecha);

                    $registros = new ArrayCollection();
                    foreach($datos as $dato){
                        $rtime = new AsistenciaRegistroTiempo();
                        if(!is_null($dato->getFechahoraentrada()))
                            $rtime->setHoraentrada($dato->getFechahoraentrada());
                        if(!is_null($dato->getFechahorasalida()))
                            $rtime->setHorasalida($dato->getFechahorasalida());
                        $rtime->setTiporegistro($dato->getTiporegistro());
                        $registros->add($rtime);
                    }

                }

                $form->add('registrosusuario', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType::class,
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'allow_delete' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'data' => $registros,
                ));
            });


        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $submittedData = $event->getData();
                $asistencia = $event->getForm()->getData();
                if (!strlen($submittedData['fecha'])) {
                    return;
                }
                $fecha = new \DateTime($submittedData['fecha']);
                $datos = $this->em->getRepository('ControlAsistenciaBundle:RegistroTiempo')
                    ->ObtenerRegistrosFechaUsuario($asistencia->getUsuario(),$fecha);

                $registros = new ArrayCollection();
                foreach($datos as $dato){
                    $rtime = new AsistenciaRegistroTiempo();
                    if(!is_null($dato->getFechahoraentrada()))
                        $rtime->setHoraentrada($dato->getFechahoraentrada());
                    if(!is_null($dato->getFechahorasalida()))
                        $rtime->setHorasalida($dato->getFechahorasalida());
                    $rtime->setTiporegistro($dato->getTiporegistro());
                    $registros->add($rtime);
                }

                $submittedData['registrosusuario'] = $registros;
                $event->setData($submittedData);
            });

        $builder->get('fecha')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $fecha = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();

                $asistencia = $form->getData();
                if(is_null($fecha)){
                    $registros =  array();
                } else {
                    $datos = $this->em->getRepository('ControlAsistenciaBundle:RegistroTiempo')
                        ->ObtenerRegistrosFechaUsuario($asistencia->getUsuario(), $fecha);
                    $registros = new ArrayCollection();
                    foreach($datos as $dato){
                        $rtime = new AsistenciaRegistroTiempo();
                        if(!is_null($dato->getFechahoraentrada()))
                            $rtime->setHoraentrada($dato->getFechahoraentrada());
                        if(!is_null($dato->getFechahorasalida()))
                            $rtime->setHorasalida($dato->getFechahorasalida());
                        $rtime->setTiporegistro($dato->getTiporegistro());
                        $registros->add($rtime);
                    }
                }
                $form->add('registrosusuario', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType::class,
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'allow_delete' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'data' => $registros,
                ));
            }
        );

        //Data Transformer
        $builder->get('fecha')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($asistencia) {
                    $fechausuario = null;
                    if($asistencia instanceof  \DateTime) {
                        $fechausuario = $asistencia;
                        $mes = $fechausuario->format("m");
                        $dia = $fechausuario->format("d");
                        $anio = $fechausuario->format("Y");
                        $hora = $fechausuario->format("H");
                        $minuto = $fechausuario->format("i");

                        $fechausuario = new \DateTime($anio.'-'.$mes.'-'.$dia.' '.$hora.':'.$minuto);
                    }else{
                        if(strlen($asistencia)==10){
                            $partesfecha = explode("-",$asistencia);
                            $fechausuario = new \DateTime($partesfecha[2].'-'.$partesfecha[1].'-'.$partesfecha[0]);
                        }
                    }

                    return $fechausuario;
                },
                function ($asistencia) {
                    $fechausuario = null;
                    if($asistencia instanceof  \DateTime) {
                        $fechausuario = $asistencia;
                        $mes = $fechausuario->format("m");
                        $dia = $fechausuario->format("d");
                        $anio = $fechausuario->format("Y");
                        $hora = $fechausuario->format("h");
                        $minuto = $fechausuario->format("i");

                        $fechausuario = new \DateTime($anio.'-'.$mes.'-'.$dia.' '.$hora.':'.$minuto);
                    }else{
                        if(strlen($asistencia)==10){
                            $partesfecha = explode("-",$asistencia);
                            $fechausuario = new \DateTime($partesfecha[2].'-'.$partesfecha[1].'-'.$partesfecha[0]);
                        }
                    }

                    return $fechausuario;
                }
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\Apps\ControlAsistenciaBundle\Entity\Asistencia',
        ));
    }
}
```

AsistenciaRegistroTiempoType.php

```
class AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('tiporegistro',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => 'ControlAsistenciaBundle:TipoRegistroTiempo',
                'choice_label' => 'titulo',
                'expanded'=>false,
                'placeholder' => false,
                'multiple'=>false,
                'label'=>'Tipo',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC');
                },
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'compound' => false
            ))
            ->add('horaentrada', TimeType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'html5' => false,
                'label' => "Entrada",
                'with_seconds'=>false

            ))
            ->add('horasalida', TimeType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'html5' => false,
                'label' => "Salida",
                'with_seconds'=>false
            ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Company\Apps\ControlAsistenciaBundle\Entity\AsistenciaRegistroTiempo',
        ));
    }
```

Cualquier idea que me pueda ayudar será bienvenida.
Gracias.